# Saving CSV file to documents directory folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsdocumentdirectory

I am writing a registration app that is supposed to save a CSV file in the documents directory folder. I would like to look at the output and see what happens when I open the CSV file in excel. I navigated to the documents directory folder by finding out where it should be saved using this code snippet:

```
NSLog(@"Info Saved");
NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                    URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

Here is my code for saving the information put into the 11 text fields in the registration form:

```
- (IBAction)saveFormButton:(id)sender {

// saves text field data in comma separated CSV file format
NSString *formData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@\n",
                      self.nameTextfield.text, self.emailTextfield.text,
                      self.phoneTextfield.text, self.termTextfield.text,
                      self.schoolTextfield.text, self.graduationTextfield.text,
                      self.gpaTextfield.text, self.degreeTextfield.text,
                      self.interestTextfield.text, self.groupTextfield.text,
                      self.appliedTextfield.text];

// get document directory path
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                    NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

// append results.csv onto doc path
NSString *event = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"results.csv"];

// creates folder if it does not exist
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentDirectoryPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:event contents:nil attributes:nil];
}


NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:event];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[formData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
```

Should I be seeing a file in that specific folder I have navigated to?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am very new to iOS development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more elegant way with less code

```
 // Content of file
 NSString* str= @"str,hey,so,good";

 // Writing    
 NSString *root = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.csv"];
 [str writeToFile:root atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

 // Reading
 NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:root encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

 NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

The result:

```
2015-07-15 15:52:56.267 ObjC[2927:15828] str,hey,so,good
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
NSString *event = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"results.csv"];
```

to:

```
NSString *event = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];
```

This makes sure that the path is correctly formatted. Also, you seem to be checking to see if "documentDirectoryPath" exists before creating the file rather than the filename itself. Change:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentDirectoryPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:event contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

to:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:event]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:event contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```